# What track plays in the background of Mark Wahlberg’s introduction in Transformers 4?

Tags: transformers, music-identification, transformers-age-of-extinction, transformers-live-action-series

In the movie *Transformers: Age of Extinction*, what is the song played in the background during the introduction of the hero (played by Mark Wahlberg)? It plays at time 3:15 in the timeline of the movie.

Comment: I haven't watched the movie yet, but this might help you.  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2109248/soundtrack             http://www.tfw2005.com/transformers-news/transformers-movie-just-movie-31/transformers-4-age-of-extinction-soundtrack-list-180557/

Comment: Comment boxes aren't meant for Thanks and stuff, just stuff that will add to the question. If you like a comment you are supposed to vote it up or just appreciate it. The thanks is appreciated if it answered your question, though, I will consider putting it in a answer and adding more evidence so it can appreciated as canon and help future users.

Comment: I really hope it’s *[The Touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Touch_(Stan_Bush_song))*, given that this is a Transformers movie starring [Mark Wahlberg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYAAbbuEpnw).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite , no, i think its not. The lyrics in the movie are starting like "Keep it calm and"..And the music is melodious

Comment: Yeah, if there’s a golden opportunity for awesomeness to be missed, the Transformers movies will miss it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found it: it’s a track by the Imagine Dragons called *All for You*.

Comment: This is the song.. :-). I don't have reputation to up vote the answer..

Answer (score -2):

All for you by imagine dragons I had to Google it and I couldn't download the song on pandora as it's not on their song list

Comment: That answer was [already provided and accepted by the OP](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/60978/122024) nine years ago.