# What are these two songs played in "Transformers: Age of Extinction"?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, music-identification, transformers-age-of-extinction

Could anyone please tell me the titles of the songs played from 6:50 to 7:57 minutes (two songs, one after another) in *Transformers: Age of Extinction*?

Answer (score 2):

The first song (played as Tessa drives up with her friends) is *First Light*, by Racing Glaciers.

The second song (played as Tessa walks up the driveway) is *Tessa*, composed by Steve Jablonsky.

Source: a copy of the movie, boredom and Google/Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the movie, (and probably won't) but 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformers:_Age_of_Extinction_%E2%80%93_The_Score) seems to have the complete score. With that and YouTube to hear a couple minutes of each you should be able to ID those songs.

The *songs* and score are written and composed by Steve Jablonsky.

1. "Decision"      4:20
2. "Best Thing That Ever Happened"     2:06
3. "I'm an Autobot"    5:06
4. "Optimus is Alive"      2:17
5. "Cemetery Wind"     5:53
6. "His Name is Shane and He Drives"   5:17
7. "Hacking the Drone"     2:05
8. "Transformium"      3:24
9. "Galvatron is Online"   1:56
10. "Your Creators Want You Back"   3:26
11. "The Final Knight"      4:07
12. "Punch Hold Slide Repeat"   2:12
13. "The Presence of Megatron"      2:51
14. "Galvatron is Active"   4:13
15. "Have Faith Prime"      1:29
16. "Hong Kong Chase"   1:43
17. "The Legend Exists"     1:16
18. "Dinobot Charge"    6:37
19. "That's a Big Magnet"   2:51
20. "Drive Backwards"   2:05
21. "Honor to the End"      5:18
22. "Leave Planet Earth Alone"      3:47
23. "The Knight Ship"   3:21

So, depending on the length of the opening credits, you are probably looking for *Best Thing That Ever Happened* and *I'm an Autobot*.

Comment: We generally try to discourage answers that are simply links to other sites.

Comment: Sorry about that (Still I disagree, and I don't know why this answer is considered "not useful"). I'm actually pointing to wiki to tell him where to find the song's titles (he could easily googled that himself prior to posting his question), but I'm expecting him to do the work to check in You Tube for which song is played which minute. His question didn't show research effort, so I thought that that I would just point to the resources (Wikipedia + You Tube), instead of "giving fish".

Comment: Should I rewrite everything as a comment instead of an answer then? Just tell me the _best practices_. Thanks.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/601/bring-the-content-here) for some of the reasons why we do this. SE aims to be a repository of information, not a signpost. Linking sources or additional info is great, but the main information should be here.

Comment: Understood. I edited the answer to include the content, so know even if the link went dead the answer would remain in SFF.

Comment: Reverted my downvote. It can/should also be noted that there are needle-drop songs *not* by Jablonski in the film. [Imagine Dragons did at least one song used in the movie.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/60961/5184)